# Command Pattern: relationship between Client and Invoker

Tags: design-patterns, uml

I'm studying design patterns and I've a question about the command pattern: I don't understand why every class diagram that I've seen (for example, look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern or http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html) doesn't show a relationship beetween Client and Invoker, since the client creates an instance of the Invoker class.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Can someone post a simple example of how to implement a Client that doesn't instantiate an Invoker but it's only responsible for the handling of concrete commands and receivers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there may be a relation but there is no must for a relation.

Example:

First we have a `Command` interface

```
public interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

with some implentations...

```
public class CopyFilesCommand implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // copy some files
    }
}

public class ZipFilesCommand implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // collect the copied files to a zip archive
    }
}

public class MailZipFileCommand implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // mail the zip file to some address
    }
}
```

now imagine a server application with a basic configuration

```
public class Config {
    private static final Config INSTANCE = new Config();

    private List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    private Config() {
        // intentionally empty
    }

    public static List<Command> getCommands() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(INSTANCE.commands);
    }

    public static void addCommand(Command command) {
        INSTANCE.commands.add(command);
    }
}
```

a client Method can now set up the configuration like this

```
public class Client {
    public void setUpConfig() {
        Config.addCommand(new CopyFilesCommand());
        Config.addCommand(new ZipFilesCommand());
        Config.addCommand(new MailZipFileCommand());
    }
}
```

and some service running inside our server application could then take the commands and invoke them

```
public class Invoker implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Command command : Config.getCommands()) {
            command.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

you see Client and Invoker do not know each other (i.e. they do not have a relation) but still work together using the commands they both know.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I can't imagine a scenario where a client isn't responsible for the creation and the usage of the instance of the Invoker class. Probably I did not understand your example.

Comment: I have integrated my comment. I pressed enter before its completion.